# Magento1.9: How can i add image of product using soap api

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, soap-api-v2

i have use this code:

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$productId = 2;
$file = array(
    'content' => '/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCAAXABcDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDLooor8XP4DCiiigAooooAKKKKAP/Z',
    'mime' => 'image/jpeg'
);

$result = $proxy->catalogProductAttributeMediaCreate(
    $session,
    $productId,
    array('file' => $file, 'label' => 'Label', 'position' => '100', 'types' => array('thumbnail'), 'exclude' => 0)
);
```

but image not added in product ,,
can any one guide me how can i add images with products using soap api ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below example :

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/productImages.html

```
 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

    $newImage = array(
        'file' => array(
            'name' => 'file_name',
            'content' => base64_encode(file_get_contents('product.jpg')),
            'mime'    => 'image/jpeg'
        ),
        'label'    => 'Cool Image Through Soap',
        'position' => 2,
        'types'    => array('small_image'),
        'exclude'  => 0
    );

    $imageFilename = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.create', array('Sku', $newImage));


    var_dump($imageFilename);

    // Newly created image file
    var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.list', 'Sku'));

    $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.update', array(
        'Sku',
        $imageFilename,
        array('position' => 2, 'types' => array('image') /* Lets do it main image for product */)
    ));

    // Updated image file
    var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.list', 'Sku'));

    // Remove image file
    $proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.remove', array('Sku', $imageFilename));

    // Images without our file
    var_dump($proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.list', 'Sku'));
```

**hope it will help you.**